# How can I use Javascript fetch() to get REST paginated data without recursion?

Tags: javascript, rest, recursion, react-native, pagination

I am working with a REST API that has paginated data and I need to be able to access all of the pages at once using Javascript in my React Native app with fetch/promise. In Python I would be able to do it like this:

```
new_result = requests.get(url+offset)
while len(new_result) == 1000:
    new_result = requests.get(url+offset).json()
    result += new_result
    offset += 1000
```

I can't seem to find an analogous solution without going recursive which I would like to avoid. Is there a way to accomplish this in Javascript? If recursion is the only way forward are there any recommended patterns?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with recursion. It's the obvious solution, so you should use it! Why do you want to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to async/await, it's fine to 'recur' from your `then()` callback. It looks like recursion, but you're not actually increasing the stack with every iteration.

This is because the callback you passed to `then()` is indirectly called from the main event loop.

You simply can't use a straight-up loop because the process is asynchronous, unless you use co-routines (requires a browser that supports generators) or async/await.

Comment: so the best solution would be something along the lines of `doSomething().then(if(needs_another_loop){doSomething})`?

Comment: Presumably it would be:

`doSomething().then(if(needs_another_loop){ return doSomething()})`

Comment: @grrrrrr `doSomething().then(result => needsAnotherLevel(result) ? doSomething() : result)`

Comment: @Bergi, wouldn't i need to combine each level of results? `doSomething().then(result => needsAnotherLevel(result) ? result.concat(doSomething()) : result)`

Comment: Yes, something *along the lines of that* :-)

Answer (score 2):

If it is ok for you using `async`/`await`, you can do something like this:

```
let newResult = await fetch(url+offset)
while (newResult.length === 1000) {
    newResult = await requests.get(url+offset);
    result += await newResult.json();
    offset += 1000;
}
```